# Create a mysql event with condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I currently have a mysql database where I keep data about rented books. When somebody rents a book, I save on the database an expiration date.

So, I want to create an mysql event to update the book status when it is not returned in time. How can I create this event?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
CREATE EVENT `EXPIRE` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1
 HOUR STARTS '2016-07-16 00:00:00.000000' ENDS '2018-07-29 
00:00:00.000000' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO DO IF 
mtl_rents.dateLimit=CURRENT_DATE THEN
        UPDATE mtl_rents SET mtl_rents.status='Expired'
    END IF
```

But I'm getting Syntax errors on the IF.

Answer (score 2):

You have double `DO` at the end of the third line.

Comment: Thank you, but after some checks, I ended up changing my event.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some checks, I ended up updating my event to this:

```
CREATE EVENT `EXPIRAR` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1
 HOUR STARTS '2016-07-16 00:00:00.000000' ENDS '2018-07-29 
00:00:00.000000' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE mtl_rents SET mtl_rents.status='Expired' WHERE mtl_rents.dateLimit = CURDATE() AND mtl_rents.status!= 'Expired'
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Skip that `EVENT`.  Instead, when the book is rented, insert a row into another table.  This would contain (at least) the book_id, and due_date.

Then have a program (not an `EVENT`, since MySQL cannot send email) that runs every night (via `cron` or `at`) to check this table and send warning notices (or whatever) or delete rows that are dealt with.  This could also update the `book_status`.

Comment: The thing is: the computer is not always turned on. And I also want to check on this days

Comment: Run the check every hour.  Most runs will do nothing.  (This is often a good idea, especially since the computer could be dead when the job should run.)